# Is there a version of Java that supports lexically extracting the name of a local variable, so that it is available at runtime?

Tags: java, parsing, debugging, compilation, lexical-analysis

Is there a version of Java that supports a syntax similar to this?:

```
Integer myInteger = new Integer(0);

if (debug) {
    System.out.println($myInteger + ": " + myInteger);
}
```

where

```
$myInteger
```

is (nearly) lexically identical to

```
"myInteger"
```

Thus... the parser sees a (nearly) identical stream of tokens, given either of these two statements:

1. `System.out.println($myInteger + ": " + myInteger);`
2. `System.out.println("myInteger" + ": " + myInteger);`

So, in the above example, the `$` is the *nameOf* lexical operator that converts the identified variable to a string representing the variable's name.  To be clear: I made up this syntax (including the $ token and the *nameOf* operator) to illustrate my question.  I've used the word *nearly* because I imagine that the two token streams corresponding to the two examples I gave would not truly be identical; rather they would be *nearly* identical.  The difference being the ability to generate a compiler error if the variable isn't defined:

```
Integer myInteger = new Integer(0);

if (debug) {
    System.out.println($myIntegr + ": " + myInteger);  <-- Error: myIntgr is not defined.
}
```

Such a Java language feature would be helpful when debugging code and eliminates the risk that the variable name and a String implicitly defined that holds the variable name will fall out of sync as source code is inevitably refactored.

Comment: Are you looking specifically into support that would make it possible to do this with (local) variables directly, or do you plan to debug whole objects (without reflection), like `System.out.println(someObj)` to output something like `ClassName{ field1 = someValue, field2 = "someString" }`. Because if the later then there are annotation libraries for that, by keeping the `toString()` method up-to-date with your fields in an annotated class. One such lib is [@AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md), there are probably others.

Comment: There isn't any such thing in Java.  And you can't do this using reflection.